# Statistics/Expected Value/Indicator Variables

Tags: statistics

I was having trouble with this problem for a class I'm taking:

We shuffle a standard deck of 52 cards. What is the expected number of quartets of adjacent cards that form a four-of-a-kind? For example, a shuffled deck may look like ...A♠A♥A♦A♣...2♥2♦2♠2♣....
(Hint: using indicator method.)

I tried solving it as follows:

$X=$# of quartets, $I(j) = 1$ if there is a quartet of cards with value $j$ ($1\leq j\leq 13$), zero otherwise.

$E[X] = 13\cdot P(I(j)) = 13\cdot P(I(1)) = 13\cdot{1\over 53}\cdot {1\over 52}\cdot{1\over 51}$

However, this doesn't seem like the right answer, for multiple reasons (it doesn't take into account the positions for the cards, it doesn't take into account the fact that it becomes more likely to pick a certain card as you go through the deck, etc.)

I was wondering if the problem was with how $I$ defined $I(j)$, or just with the calculation of $P(I(j))$?

Comment: There are $49$ places where four of a kind might start.  Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{49}$ be the indicators for each and use Linearity.

Comment: This question (more or less) has come up a lot in the last few hours.  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2389837/expected-value-of-three-consecutive-cards-of-same-value) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2389689/expected-value-of-adjacent-pairs-in-a-deck-of-52) for example.  What is the source of these questions?

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify, the probability would still be constant for each X(i)? As in, regardless if the first four were Aces or not, the probability of the next four being all 2s remains unchanged?

Comment: As for the other posts, I can't say for certain if this is the case or not, but they might be other people in the same class as me, as we have our final exam next week

Comment: To your question:  no, but that is not important.  Knowing that the first four are all aces changes the probability but the whole point of Linearity is that dependence is irrelevant.  For example, it is impossible that both the first and second cards are the first in a four-of-a-kind set.  Doesn't matter.